# 100% height OR 100% width

Tags: css, height, width

How do I make it so an image fills a tile with a set size no matter what and keep its aspect ratio? For instance, if an image is wide enough it expands to also be tall enough with the overflow hidden and vice versa. This is what I have so far but if an image needs to be adjust for 100% height it doesn't expand the width beyond the box and leaves the image distorted.

```
.box{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.image{
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}

<div class="box">
  <img class="image" src="/img.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: use `width:100%; height:auto;` or `height:100%; width:auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and used the following CSS in my div:

```
background: url("dynamic-img.jpg") repeat scroll center center / cover  rgb(191, 30, 46)
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is the only CSS-only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative css way is to utilize `cover`

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
```

See source for details: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/