# How to make video's width 100% or height 100%

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm having the same issue as [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328009/100-height-or-100-width) but i'm trying to do it on `<video/>` element.
I want to make video element sometimes `width: 100%`, and sometimes `height: 100%` by aspect ratio of it.

Here's my css

```
.remoteVideo-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(45, 48, 53);
}

.remoteVideo {
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

here's my jsx

```
      <div className="remoteVideo-container">
          <video
            className="remoteVideo"
            autoPlay
            ref={this.remoteVideo}
            muted
          ></video>
      </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it, you missed the sizing of the video tag. object-position could be also handy :

```
.remoteVideo {
  height:100%; /* or is max-height:100%; */
  width:100%;  /* or is max-width:100%;  */
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position:center;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

Possible example to run in full page to test behavior on resize, or version based on `max-height`/`max-width` `100%` https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGNzzNj to shrink video if it becomes bigger than the screen .Up to you to choose value for height and width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.remoteVideo-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(45, 48, 53);
}

.remoteVideo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="remoteVideo-container">
  <video class="remoteVideo" autoplay muted poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg">
    <source  src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source  src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by a small css hack.
Set min-width and min-height to 100% and then height and width to auto to prevent from stretching or zooming in the video.
And a bit more to center the video.

```
.remoteVideo {
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: I don't want my video do cover all the screen. I want to make it as wide or high as screen, according to it's aspect ratio.

Comment: For example if the video's width is more than it's height, width must be 100%, height auto