# How to make background video always fit the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to somehow recreate Apple's Apple TV+ page. They have a background video that scales to fit the page (without changing dimensions, it is just in the center of their page) https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-plus/. But when I am setting height to 100% and make browser window smaller in height video gets bezels on left and right. Tried min-width=100%; but it doesn't seem to be working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container_video">
   <video class="liveflex" autoplay loop>
       <source src="resources/large_2x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container_video {
    display: flex !important;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: auto !important;
    z-index: -1;
}
video.background {
    display: flex !important;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: auto !important;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: `video.liveflex { position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100% }`

Comment: Looks like  a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882244/how-to-make-videos-width-100-or-height-100/59885689

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try leveraging [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

> The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>   filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio
>   does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be
>   clipped to fit.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.video-background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

.video-background video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="video-background">
    <video class="liveflex" autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
  <main>
    <article>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam efficitur nisl non cursus tincidunt. Morbi tellus ex, placerat eu pharetra at, tristique et felis. Cras quis turpis porta, viverra risus sit amet, eleifend elit. Aenean placerat venenatis
        elit, sed molestie lacus elementum et. Phasellus nisl mauris, cursus eu sodales sed, volutpat et magna. Sed enim nulla, semper aliquam mauris rhoncus, hendrerit ornare dolor. Proin diam ante, tempor in egestas quis, sodales viverra ligula. Aenean
        massa eros, semper sit amet mattis vitae, ultrices sit amet nunc. Suspendisse ultricies mattis elit ut pretium. Aenean euismod commodo augue, quis cursus mi ullamcorper sed. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h1>Foo Bar!</h1>
      <p>Morbi suscipit pretium enim, vel sollicitudin ex varius et. Nullam consequat vitae lectus ut facilisis. Suspendisse tincidunt consectetur nisi vitae ultricies. Etiam non pellentesque odio. Ut hendrerit tincidunt pretium. Curabitur nec imperdiet
        sapien. Nullam sed sem massa. Nullam dapibus ut libero nec tempus. Phasellus gravida, risus quis congue viverra, massa augue scelerisque libero, molestie pharetra elit mi sit amet nisl. Fusce ac gravida velit.</p>
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely help if your container has a set height.

```
.container_video {
    display: flex !important;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto !important;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
video {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```